# How can I disable the "open in app" banner on ios safari for pages that support universal links?

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, ios-universal-links

After registering a path as a universal link via apple-app-site-association, I'm seeing that on pageloads on iOS safari, when I have the app installed, the system will inject an "open in app" banner on the top of the screen.

I'd like to disable this banner while preserving universal link support for this page. I don't see any official way to do this; is there any method, however hacky or unconventional, to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT:

In my answer below, I realized that only loads when the app is not installed. What you are trying to accomplish may not be possible. Since the AASA file is installed on the device, Safari will automatically associate that web page with an app and therefore load the banner in the browser. I don't believe this is an HTML element that you can just remove with a JQuery call. A solution to this would be to use a redirecting link as your Universal Link. This way if the app is installed, the app will open, and if not then it will redirect to your site which isn't recognized as a Universal Link and will not show the banner. [Branch](http://branch.io) is the a solid deep linking solution that uses redirects, so you won't have to deal with the Apple banner.

### **Removing banner when app is not installed**

Make sure the smart app banner meta tag is not being loaded on your page. If you see this tag, take it out:

```
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=myAppStoreID, affiliate-data=myAffiliateData, app-argument=myURL">
```

Comment: That tag isn't present

Comment: So far, could not find a way to disable Smart App Banner on Safari mobile