# How do I disable the default in-app banner in safari

Tags: javascript, ios, safari

The site uses smartbanner.js to display a banner to go to the app if the site is open on the phone. But ios has a standard banner, which by default is triggered if universal link via apple-app-site-association are used, even without connecting <meta name="apple-itunes-app"... and it turns out that on ios both banners are shown. How can this be avoided?

There was a similar question here [How can I disable the "open in app" banner on ios safari for pages that support universal links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49421203/how-can-i-disable-the-open-in-app-banner-on-ios-safari-for-pages-that-support), but smartbanner.js was not used there and there was no problem displaying two banners at once and the solution does not fit